# ParseReact.Mixin how do I listen for changes to this.data?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

I have a React component that observes data on a Parse server.

```
mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],
observe: function() {
   var query = new Parse.Query('Item');
   return {
      items: query
   };
}
```

In the `render` method I do receive my `items` and that work well. But, I want to be able to listen for when `this.data.items` will change it's value.

I'm aware of the regular lifecycle methods, but in them I have no way of checking if `this.data.items` is the same as before the update.

```
componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {},
componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {},
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you need a "receiving data" callback?
Now there are no such a callback.
See this [issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/issues/83).

You can override "_receiveData" function in class extended ParseComponent by yourself though I'm not sure it's the right way for your situation.

```
_receiveData(name, value) {
  this.data[name] = value;
  delete this._pendingQueries[name];
  delete this._queryErrors[name];
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Where did you get the function body from?

Comment: ParseComponent.js  
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/blob/master/src/ParseComponent.js